# Container Not Accessible From Other Container with docker run

Tags: docker, jdbc, docker-compose

Here's the situation:

When I run a MySQL 5.7 docker image locally (docker-compose) using the

```
container_name: test-mysql-docker
```

it works fine. My JDBC program in another docker container can access the MySQL container via the container_name.

However, when I push that MySQL 5.7 image to my docker hub account and then try to run it in a separate command window, it does not work (see run command I'm using below). The problem: The JDBC program running in another docker container cannot access it and gives the "tried three times" error message.

I thus think I have incorrect syntax in my run command below. After MySQL downloads from the run command below, I am able to access the MySQL container from outside docker so it's up and the data I need is there. I'm therefore thinking, it's just the container_name that's wrong, but looking for the experts here to give me ideas.

Here's my run command which successfully brings down the MySQL 5.7 image (reachable outside docker but not from another docker container as when run locally using "docker-compose up")

```
$ docker run -it -p 3307:3306 --name test-mysql-docker -v /Users/.../ZipCodeLookup.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/ZipCodeLookup.sql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=thepass docker-account/mysql:5.7
```

I'm assuming to run a docker container from docker hub, I need to specify all the parameters manually as the command above (which I don't have to do when using docker-compose).

Can anyone see what's wrong or possibly missing with the run command above that would keep another container from accessing, via JDBC, the MySQL container using "test-mysql-docker" as the container name?

Thanks very much in advance,

Comment: in the container, what's the url you use to access MySQL?

Comment: Working JDBC string if I run both containers using docker-compose: final String DATABASE_URL =
                "jdbc:mysql://test-mysql-docker:3306/ZipCodeLookup?useSSL=false&" 
                 +    "serverTimezone=America/New_York&user=root&password=thepass&autoReconnect=true";

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're correctly using `test-mysql-docker:3306` as the url for accessing the db from JDBC, you need to attach them to the same custom network. The default bridge network does not work.

```
docker network create mynet
docker run -d --net mynet -p 3307:3306 --name test-mysql-docker -v /Users/.../ZipCodeLookup.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/ZipCodeLookup.sql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=thepass docker-account/mysql:5.7 
docker run -it --net mynet JDBC
```

Comment: Excellent!!! This worked, THANK YOU. I need to focus now on some way to make Docker a bit less complex to work with.